# How to redirect only stdout in crontab?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

I want to only redirect `stdout` to a logfile from `crontab`, and let crontab notify me by mail on errors.

If I'd want to redirect both std and err stream, I'd go for `2>&1`:

```
MAILTO=john@me.com
0 23 * * * /home/john/import.sh > /home/john/logs/backup.log 2>&1
```

But wouldn't this prevent crontab catching on errors and sending a mail notification? So that's why I'm looking for a way to only redirect the stdout.

My problem is that my `import.sh` script runs a mysql import.
And oddly crontab is sending my emails about it, even though there is nor error:

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Importing from file '/tmp/my.csv' to table `mytable` in MySQL Server at /var%2Frun%2Fmysqld%2Fmysqld.sock using 3 threads
[Worker001] Records: 340086  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
[Worker002] Records: 351334
...
File '/tmp/my.csv' was imported in 1 min 9.9572 sec at 59.91 MB/s
```

So I'm looking for a way to still log those statements, but notify me only in error case.

---

Update:
Image a crontab as follows:

```
*/1 * * * * /opt/test.sh
```

test.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "just testing"
exit 0
```

Result: the crontab will **always** send an email notification, even though it's simply a stdout with success code. But why? How can I prevent this?

Comment: That's exactly the problem: so far I don't have the `2>&1` descriptor, which leads to email notifications even in `info` and `warning` log statements. But I only want to receive errors... If I add `2>&1`, then nothing will be reported at all, as everything goes to logfile directly.

Comment: It seems what you actually want to do is redirect both stdout *and* any non-error messages in stderr.

Comment: The problem is that mysql also writes to both stdout and stderr (typically, data to stdout, all else (prompts, session information, echoed commands) to stderr. So you need to apply redirection inside the script, around the mysql execution. But then you need to detect any actual mysql errors textually.

Comment: See my update with a simple echo script.

Comment: normally cron send an email if your script produces any output no matter it succeeded or failed, so with your test script it still produce output and cron inform you about the result by sending mail, you can remove `echo..... ` to verify again then test another time by doing `exit 1`, for the later, you will get a mail. this applies to the same thing as @Paul_Pedant pointed above.

Comment: Ok you're correct. So basically that's probably the problem for `mysqlsh`: it produces output, and crontab then forwards that output by mail. So the question is, how can could prevent crontab sending "info" output?

Comment: for that as pointed by @Paul_Pedant, you need work on your mysql.sh script to silent its output if succeeded

Comment: Mailing the output is a last resort -- there is nothing else cron could do with it except to silently throw it away. You can throw it away yourself to /dev/null, or arrange to log it, but cron cannot possibly know what output you consider to be an error. Oracle, for example, throws well-documented errors starting like XXX-nnnnn (ORA-10195, SQL-23073), anything else being commentary. mysql may not be as cooperative. No exit status code is going to sum up the result of an sql session: maybe you did a typo, corrected it and carried on: that does not constitute a failed session.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something as follows:

```
0 23 * * * :> /home/john/logs/backup.log && /home/john/import.sh 2> >(tee -a /home/john/logs/backup.log) >> /home/john/logs/backup.log
```

`stderr` will go both to `stderr` AND the file (via the `tee` command), while `stdout` will go only to the file.

I have to append (the `-a` of the `tee` command and the `>>` of the stdout to the file) to ensure that that the `tee` and the redirection don't override each other.

I have the `:> /home/john/logs/backup.log` at the beginning to truncate the log before each time the cron runs, since we're appending to the file due the reason smentioned above.

#### Update

I didn't like the fact that in my previous answer there were two processes appending to the same file, which forced me to truncate it first. I've found another solution:

```
0 23 * * * (( /home/john/import.sh 2> >(tee /proc/self/fd/3) 1>&3 3>&- ) 3>&1 1>&2) |cat > /home/john/logs/backup.log
```

It only works with `bash`, not with POSIX `sh`, so you'll need to change your shell in the crontab file with `SHELL=/bin/bash`.

Here's an attempt to explain what I did here:

1. `((...) 3>&1 1>&2)`

This will create a new file descriptor **3** that will redirect to what fd 1 holds - which is the pipe to `cat`. fd 1 will go instead to what fd 2 holds - which is the terminal (or in your case, the input of the cron).

2. `/home/john/import.sh 2> >(tee ... ) 1>&3 3>&-`

The script will direct it’s stdout to what fd 3 holds (that is the pipe to `cat`.), and it’s stderr to tee.

It will close fd 3 because it's not needed anymore - the stdout of the script already goes to what 3 was holding.

3. `tee /proc/self/fd/3`

The tee will write both to what fd 3 holds (again, the pipe to `cat`) **and** to terminal (or in your case, as an input to the cron).

4. `(...) |cat > /home/john/logs/backup.log`

`cat` will read the stream from its stdin, and will write to the the `backup.log` file.

###### Result:

- The script will write it’s stdout to the stdin of `cat`.
- The script will also write it’s stderr to `tee`.

  - `tee` will write it’s input (the stderr of the script) both to:

    - the terminal
    - the stdin of `cat`.
- `cat` gets it’s input both from:

  - the stdout of the script
  - the stderr of the script (via `tee`)
- `cat` will write what it gets in stdin to the file.
- The only thing that will be actually go back to the cron is the
  stderr of the script (again, via `tee`).

Answer (score 1):

crontab

```
MAILTO=john@me.com
0 23 * * * /home/john/import.sh
```

import.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3>&1 # Save a reference to current STDOUT as file descriptor 3
# Redirect stdout and stderr to the log file
exec >>"/home/john/logs/backup.log" 2>&1

echo "$(date +%Y%m%dT%H%M) info: job started"

output_from_mysql_import_operation=$(
  mysql <data-to-import.sql 2>&1
)
mysql_exit_status=$?
if [[ $mysql_exit_status != 0 ]]; then
  # This is sent to file descriptor 3, which is the original stdout
  # Thus, cron will collect this and send an email
  cat <<EOF >&3
cron job failed for script $0 at $(date +%Y%m%dT%H%M)

An error occurred during the import operation.

The mysql exit status code was $mysql_exit_status.

The output from mysql follows.

$output_from_mysql_import_operation
EOF

  # This will end up in the log file
  cat <<EOF
$(date +%Y%m%dT%H%M): error: mysql exited with a non-zero exit status"

The mysql exit status code was $mysql_exit_status.

The output from mysql follows.

$output_from_mysql_import_operation

Exiting script
EOF
  exit 1
fi

echo "$output_from_mysql_import_operation"
echo
echo "$(date +%Y%m%dT%H%M) info: job completed successfully"
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the import.sh file actually do ? Assuming it is running a command like `mysql`, it should return an **exit code** based on the execution outcome. Then check the exit code.

Try:

```
echo $?
```

And check that a failed statement returns a non-zero value.

So I would suggest that you do error handling from within your script and send the logs by mail in case of errors. Log both stdout and stderr to a file, but don't rely on cron to filter out stderr.

Comment: Statuscode echo gave `0`, so there is no error (as written, only info and warnings). But still the cronjob reports them, and I don't know how to prevent it without losing cron-mail notifier.

Comment: See my update with a simple echo script.

Answer (score 0):

```
*/1 * * * * /opt/test.sh 1>tmp.log
```

sample test:

```
@Station:~$ ls /var 1>/dev/null
@Station:~$ ls /varr 1>/dev/null
ls: cannot access '/varr': No such file or directory
@Station:~$ # splitting args:
@Station:~$ ls 1>/dev/null -- /var
@Station:~$ ls 1>/dev/null -- /varr 
ls: cannot access '/varr': No such file or directory
@Station:~$
```